# Bash-script won't work, initializing a variable (string) with output of sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have some trouble with this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
for i in $(cat rows.txt);
do
        j = "$(sed -ne "$[i-1]p" LOB_final.html)"
        echo $j
        sed -ne "$[i-1],$[i+4]p" LOB_final.html >> ./cards/$j.txt
done;
```

I have an other file that contains the right row-numbers (not exactly, [row-1] is the relevant row). This row contains a string with spaces included and should be the name of the file.

Script works so far as expected, but initializing j don't work.

Does anyone have a tip?

Thank you.

EDIT: The goal was, to write any six rows (1 before and 4 after ans the given row) in a file. The file should be named with the 1 before row of the given row (a string with white spaces included).
Questions is cleared, thanks to all.

Comment: There are several problems with this code; use shellcheck.net to find and correct the most obvious ones first.

Comment: Remove spaces around `=` in the assignment.

Comment: Didn't know about shellcheck.net, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this, have fixed quite a few issues with your script

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
for i in $(cat rows.txt); 
do
        j="$(sed -ne "$((i-1))p" LOB_final.html)"
        echo "$j"
        sed -ne "$((i-1)),$((i+4))p" LOB_final.html >> ./cards/"$j".txt
done;
```

1. Removed space which was there in assigning j
2. $[var] replaced with $((var))
3. Expanded variables in double quotes

Comment: Thank you for your work. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to get the filename from line `i-1` and then to store that line together with the next five lines in a file with that name.

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR       { rows[$0]; next }
     FNR + 1 in rows { name = sprintf("./cards/%s.txt", $0); left = 6 }
     left > 0        { print >name; --left }' rows.txt LOB_final.html
```

This has been tested on some toy data, but since I don't know what your data looks like I can't say for certain that it will work without (minor) modifications.

It has the benefit that it will not parse the whole of `LOB_final.html` *twice* for each row number read from `rows.txt`, which your original code does. In fact, it only ever reads each file once.